# Anaconda python executes a python file in directory when I import pandas

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

This is a head scratcher.  I have a directory with Ipython notebooks and python code.  Somehow when I try to import pandas one of the pandas files attempts to execute, the execution causes the import to bomb.

```
[path]$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "path/parser.py", line 62, in <module>
    file_temp = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Using Ipython instead of python works for some reason:

```
[path]$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]:
```

To add more weirdness I can not connect to any kernels using jupyter hub in this directory.

EDIT:  This appears to be a problem with importing pandas anywhere on this machine if there is a file called parser.py.  The problem does not happen on my laptop.  This machine has Anaconda my laptop does not.  I don't have a solution on how to fix the problem though.

Comment: What happens if you rename `path/parser.py`?

Comment: looks like some dependencies aren't met and pandas tries to automatically resolves them, but fails. However those dependencies are met for ipython.

Comment: If I rename path/parser.py then the import works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a symptom of how python works, how paths in python work, and how imports in python work.  The short answer is that you can not have a file in your python path that has the same name as a python file called from a library that you import.  This creates a name collision and because the current directory is first in the python path it will attempt to use the wrong file as a dependency.  One way that this can be used to your advantage is if you want to hot patch a specific file in a library without altering the whole library.